# SAS union distinct records from datasets with similar names

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I have about 100 large datasets and within each dataset I'm hoping to extract distinct IDs to join them vertically. The datasets are unsorted,  named as data_01 , data_02, data_03 ....data_100.

Since the datasets are all very large, set them together without reducing the size is not feasible, the join didn't even move after hours of running. Therefore, I believe there is the need to reduce the datasets before stacking is necessary, and I'm here to seek some help.

I tried to create a macro to select distinct ID and sum a numerical variable,cnt, by ID before vertically joining all datasets by proc sql union. The macro is not working properly:

```
/*Get dataset names*/
proc sql noprint;
select  memname into :mylist separated by ' '
from dictionary.tables where libname= "mylib" and upcase(memname) like "DATA_%"
;
quit;

%put &mylist;

/*create union statements*/
%global nextdata;
%let nextdata =;
%macro combinedata(mylist);
  data _null_;
       datanum = countw("&mylist");
       call symput('Dataset', put(datanum, 10.));
  run;

   %do i = 1 %to  &Dataset ;
      data _null_;
          temp = scan("&mylist", &i);
          call symput("Dataname", strip(put(temp,$12.)));
      run;
       %put &Dataname;
       %put &Dataset;

        %if (&i=&Dataset) %then %do;
            %let nextdata = &nextdata.
                select id, sum(cnt)
                  from mylib.&&Dataname
                   group by id;
            %end;
        %else %do;
            %let nextdata = &nextdata.
               select id, sum(cnt)
                  from mylib.&&Dataname union
                   group by id;
         %end;

            %put nextdata = &nextdata;
    %end;


%mend combinedata;

%combinedata(&mylist);

/*execute from proc sql*/
proc sql;
    create table combined as (&nextdata);
quit;
```

I have also attempted to use proc summary, but there was not enough memory to run the following code:

```
data vneed / view=vneed;
  set data_: (keep=id cnt);
run;
proc summary data=vneed nway;
  class id;
  var cnt;
  output out=want (drop=_type_) sum=sumcnt;
run;
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: How big is each data set? How much memory do you have available?

Comment: Are the individual datasets already sorted by ID?  Or if  not sorted do they have an index on ID?

Comment: @Tom No, unfortunately they are not sorted by IDs otherwise I could have used by statement. :(

Comment: What type of variable is ID?  How many distinct values does it contain?  Why not build the data in a HASH object?

Comment: @Tom ID is in numerical, I'm not sure how many distinct values are there since I have never successfully stack all the datasets. Could it be that the ID is numerical that is causing the proc summary to run out of memory?

Comment: 23 Million observations with 2 numeric values is probably more than a HASH can hold so that is probably the reason for the error.  SAS has KB article with code for estimating memory needs of a hash object.  http://support.sas.com/kb/34/193.html  You can count the number of times the IF H.FIND() branch runs to figure out our many you have identified so far and just stop at some reasonable limit, like 1M or 10M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize the data as you go instead of trying to generate one massive query.  Then re-aggregate the aggregates.

```
proc sql ;
%do i = 1 %to  &Dataset ;
  %let dataname=mylib.%scan(&mylist,&i,%str( ));
  create table sum&i as 
   select id,sum(cnt) as cnt 
   from &dataname 
   group by id
   order by id
  ;
%end;
quit;

data want ;
  do until(last.id);
    set sum1 - sum&dataset ;
    by id;
    sumcnt+cnt;
  end;
  drop cnt;
run;
```

Comment: Generating summations across 100 + one files for over 20million IDS is going to take time.  Jut reading in the 100 files is going to take time.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of values of ID is reasonable you should be able to use a hash object.

```
data _null_ ;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    dcl hash H (ordered: "A") ;
    h.definekey ("ID") ;
    h.definedata ("ID", "SUMCNT") ;
    h.definedone () ;
  end;
  set data_: (keep=id cnt) end=eof;
  if h.find() then sumcnt=.;
  sumcnt+cnt ;
  h.replace() ;
  if eof then h.output (dataset: "WANT") ;
run ;
```

If the number of ID values is too large to fit the summary data into a HASH object you could adapt this code to stop at some reasonable number of distinct ID values to avoid memory overload and write the current summary to an actual SAS dataset and then generate the final counts by re-aggregating the intermediate datasets.  But at that point you should just use my other answer and let PROC SQL create the intermediate summary datasets instead.

Comment: It is still running...has been more than a hour now

Comment: There is not enough memory to finish the run `ERROR: Hash object added 23068656 items when memory failure occurred.
FATAL: Insufficient memory to execute DATA step program.
        Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.
ERROR: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of insufficient
       memory.`

Comment: You will need to dump and flush the hash object as it gets too big.  Then re-aggregate from the aggregates.

Comment: how do I code for that? Hash is pretty new to me.